# How can I merge two eloquent queries in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making laravel project.
There is need to merge two complex eloquent queries, not query result.
Is there any way to merge two queries?

```
    $query = DeviceReport::query();
    $query_setting_null = $query;
    $query_not_null = $query;
    
    $query_setting_null->where(function ($q) {
        $q->whereNotNull('device_setting_id');
    });
    
    if ( $company_id ) {
        $query_setting_null->whereHas('deviceSetting', function ($q) use ($company_id) {
            $q->where('company_id', $company_id);
        });
    }
    ........
    $query_not_null->where(function ($q) {
        $q->whereNull('device_setting_id');
    });

    if ( $company_id ) {
        $query_not_null->whereHas('deviceAssignment', function ($q) use ($company_id) {
            $q->where('company_id', $company_id);
        });
    }
    ........
    $query = $query_not_null->merge($query_setting_null);
    return $query;
```

My code looks some diry, sorry.
The main point is follows:

```
 $query_setting_null->where(function ($q) {
    $q->whereNotNull('device_setting_id');
});
.........
$query_not_null->where(function ($q) {
    $q->whereNull('device_setting_id');
});
.........
```

The value of device_setting_id depends after queries;

Comment: Add your code in question, what you have tried.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/merging-two-complex-eloquent-queries

Comment: Thank you, parth. I will soon add my code.

Comment: parth, Is anyway to merge two queries?

Comment: But the two whereNull og whereNotNull basicly counter acts eachother and you can leave them out?

Comment: Hi, mrhn, yes, two queries counter acts each other. I can leave them.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see your point, what exactly are you trying to do with those queries (do not say merge them) ? Explain with words because your queries are confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what you are trying but merging queries of `whereNull` and `whereNotNull` is like this:

```
$query_merged->where(function ($q) {
    $q->whereNotNull('device_setting_id');
})->orWhere(function ($q) {
    $q->whereNull('device_setting_id');
});
```

Not sure if this is what you want. Let me know if it helps.