# Does not laravel eloquent have query like WhereNotHas operation?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to distinguish 2 queries when one field is null or not null.

Let me see one table named 'report'. 
This table has some fields including 'setting' field.
When the value of 'setting'  **is null** in row of 'report' table, The query is **$query->whereHas('Setting', function($query){ $query->where('some_id', $home)})**.
When the value of 'setting' **is not null**, The query is **$query->whereHas('Device', function($query){ $query->where('some_id', $home)})**.

'setting' is the reference id of table Setting.
That is to say, I want to have exculsive query in according to setting.
I made one query, but the result is not as I want.

```
$query = Report::query();
$query->doesntHave('Setting')->whereHas('Device', function ($q) use ($home){
                $q->where('some_id', $home);
            })
            ->orWhereHas('Setting', function ($q) use ($home) {
                $q->where('some_id', $home);
            });
```

Is there any way to have query like I want?

Comment: do you want to check for null or if the fields is null you want some default value

Comment: I want to check if the value of 'setting' field in 'report' table is null or not.

Comment: `whereHas` or `whereDoesntHave` are on realtionships. If you have a column called `setting` you need to use `whereNull` or `whereNotNull` to determine if the column is null. However I'm not sure I understand your problem here. You're saying if setting is null then query the `devices` relationship and if `setting` is not null query the `setting`  relationship (which again is a column not a realationship)?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right, 'report' table has relationship with 'setting' and 'device' table.  'setting' field in 'report' table is a key to 'setting' table. 'setting' field' s real name is 'setting_id'.

Comment: If I whereNull or whereNotNull query, How can I put together 2 queries? I had proposed quesiont as follows; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842950/how-can-i-merge-two-eloquent-queries-in-laravel but not solved, so I changed query like this post